# Round depending on number of decimal places

Tags: r, rounding, tidyverse

**What I would like to to**

I would like to round all numeric values of a large data set depending on their actual decimal place.

E.g. for the `df` below, I would like to round all numbers, numbers with one decimal place to a full number and numbers with two decimal places to one decimal place.

**Update**
In the original post, I used `iris` as data set. Since `iris` does only have 1 decimal place, I added a new data set:

```
   df <- tibble(one=round(runif(100,0,10), 1),
                 two=round(runif(100,0,10), 2),
                 characters=rep("thanks",100))
```

Comment: as far as I can see `iris` data has just one decimal throughout

Comment: We can use `signif` to round to a given number of significant digits  or `round` to round to a given number of decimal places... nut sure about rounding *depending on their actual decimal place* (not sure what that means?) Also what ChrisRuehlemann said about `iris`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just count the digits after the dot and round to that value-1, i.e.

```
x <- c(4.5, 2.12, 3, 5.245)
i1 <- nchar(sub('.*\\.', '', x))

round(x, (i1-1))
#[1] 4.00 2.10 3.00 5.25
```

Comment: I didn't realise the second argument in `round` was vectorized. Nice.

Comment: For regexphobics: `i1 <- nchar(tools::file_ext(df$one))`

Comment: thank you. `round_decimals <- function(x){
  round(x, nchar(sub('.*\\.', '', x))-1)
  
}`


`df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric,round_decimals)` worked out

Answer (score 1):

DATA:

```
 v1 <- c(1.1, 1.2, 2.91, 5.9)
```

SOLUTION for vector:

Key here is the identification of numbers with 2 decimals via regular expression using `grepl`; to make the regex work, the data need to be converted to character using `as.character`. Then you can simply set up an `ifelse` clause determining that if the condition evaluates to TRUE, `round` to 1 decimal, else round to 0 decimals:

```
ifelse(grepl(".\\d{2}$", as.character(v1)), round(v1,1), round(v1,0))
```

RESULT:

```
[1] 1.0 1.0 2.9 6.0
```

SOLUTION for dataframe:

The same principle can be applied to transforming several vectors in a dataframe in one go:

```
dt <- data.frame(
  v1 = c(1.11, 2.2, 3.9, 5.55),
  v2 = c(6.99, 7.07, 8.5, 9.01))
```

The above sketched out solution just needs to be made part of a function inside an `apply` statement:

```
apply(dt, 2, function(x) ifelse(grepl(".\\d{2}$", as.character(x)), round(x,1), round(x,0)))
      v1  v2
[1,] 1.1 7.0
[2,] 2.0 7.1
[3,] 4.0 8.0
[4,] 5.5 9.0
```